# How can run a Fsharp script from an Python module

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, f#, f#-interactive

Any recommendations on how to call an F# script from a Python module?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Please note that I cannot switch my F# module to Python, or move the Python functionality to F#.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run your fsharp script from the command line then you can user pythons [subprocess](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/subprocess.html) module to run it using `Popen`.

Comment: Further to this answer if may help if your FSI script has the shebang above (assuming latest .NET or Net Core): `#!/usr/bin/env -S dotnet fsi`. Means you don't need to prefix your scripts with `dotnet fsi` either.